# Check Php variables to proper MySql type (prepare for Insert query)

Tags: php, mysql, insert

If i'm going to query mysql with this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO subscribers (email, referral_id, user_id, ip_address)
VALUES ('$user_email', '$user_refer', '$user_share', '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."')");
```

How can I check those variables (eg $user_mail), that has been just read from $_REQUEST["user_mail"], respects their MySql type (varchar(30) notnull)?

Once I saved all `$_REQUEST` in `$vars` are there any fast function to check MySql types?

Comment: Start using PDO : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496

Comment: mysqli or PDO is what you need.

Comment: if you are not checking its length before putting in sql query it simply give you error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should be using prepared statements with [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). I'd recommend PDO. There are a few [examples](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) of prepared statements w/ PDO on the PHP website.

Secondly, your app should control what gets sent to the database. You could write up custom validation rules to match each column:

```
if(strlen(trim($_REQUEST["user_mail"])) > 30){
    //Show error to user because they're not going to like having
    //their mail truncated without warning.
}
```

You can also look into using the SQL query:

```
DESCRIBE NameOfYourTable
```